# Display data in JSON format in browser using WCF project

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have created WCF project to view data in JSON format.

Service1.svc.cs

```
 public object GetData()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonString = "{\"Customers\":[{\"Id\":\"ALFKI\",\"CompanyName\":\"Alfreds Futterkiste\",\"ContactName\":\"Maria Anders\",\"ContactTitle\":\"Sales Representative\",\"Address\":\"Obere Str. 57\",\"City\":\"Berlin\",\"PostalCode\":\"12209\",\"Country\":\"Germany\",\"Phone\":\"030-0074321\",\"Fax\":\"030-0076545\"},{\"Id\":\"ANATR\",\"CompanyName\":\"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados\",\"ContactName\":\"Ana Trujillo\",\"ContactTitle\":\"Owner\",\"Address\":\"Avda. de la Constitución 2222\",\"City\":\"México D.F.\",\"PostalCode\":\"05021\",\"Country\":\"Mexico\",\"Phone\":\"(5) 555-4729\",\"Fax\":\"(5) 555-3745\"}]}";
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(ser.Serialize(jsonString));          
    }
```

**Output:**
"{\"Customers\":[{\"Id\":\"ALFKI\",\"CompanyName\":\"Alfreds Futterkiste\",\"ContactName\":\"Maria Anders\",\"ContactTitle\":\"Sales Representative\",\"Address\":\"Obere Str. 57\",\"City\":\"Berlin\",\"PostalCode\":\"12209\",\"Country\":\"Germany\",\"Phone\":\"030-0074321\",\"Fax\":\"030-0076545\"},{\"Id\":\"ANATR\",\"CompanyName\":\"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados\",\"ContactName\":\"Ana Trujillo\",\"ContactTitle\":\"Owner\",\"Address\":\"Avda. de la Constitución 2222\",\"City\":\"México D.F.\",\"PostalCode\":\"05021\",\"Country\":\"Mexico\",\"Phone\":\"(5) 555-4729\",\"Fax\":\"(5) 555-3745\"}]}"

**Expected Output:**
{"Customers":[{"Id":"ALFKI","CompanyName":"Alfreds Futterkiste","ContactName":"Maria Anders","ContactTitle":"Sales Representative","Address":"Obere Str. 57","City":"Berlin","PostalCode":"12209","Country":"Germany","Phone":"030-0074321","Fax":"030-0076545"},{"Id":"ANATR","CompanyName":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","ContactName":"Ana Trujillo","ContactTitle":"Owner","Address":"Avda. de la Constitución 2222","City":"México D.F.","PostalCode":"05021","Country":"Mexico","Phone":"(5) 555-4729","Fax":"(5) 555-3745"}]}

Can anyone suggest me how to remove escape character from my output?

Comment: Why are you even mixing the outdated `JavaScriptSerializer` with `NewtonSoft.Json`?

Comment: You're code doesn't make any sense.  Why are you serializing and deserializing in the same line?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge in WCF. If it is wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know your purpose but you can achieve your output by the below approach

```
public RootObject GetData(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string jsonString = "{\"Customers\":[{\"Id\":\"ALFKI\",\"CompanyName\":\"Alfreds Futterkiste\",\"ContactName\":\"Maria Anders\",\"ContactTitle\":\"Sales Representative\",\"Address\":\"Obere Str. 57\",\"City\":\"Berlin\",\"PostalCode\":\"12209\",\"Country\":\"Germany\",\"Phone\":\"030-0074321\",\"Fax\":\"030-0076545\"},{\"Id\":\"ANATR\",\"CompanyName\":\"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados\",\"ContactName\":\"Ana Trujillo\",\"ContactTitle\":\"Owner\",\"Address\":\"Avda. de la Constitución 2222\",\"City\":\"México D.F.\",\"PostalCode\":\"05021\",\"Country\":\"Mexico\",\"Phone\":\"(5) 555-4729\",\"Fax\":\"(5) 555-3745\"}]}";

                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);

            }
                catch (Exception ex){
                throw;
            }
        }

public class Customer
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```